# Should non-violent Apostates be killed in Islam?

Tags: sharia, apostasy, hudud

Verse [4:89] in the Quran states Apostates are to be killed:

“They wish you would disbelieve as they disbelieved so you would be alike. So do not take from among them allies until they emigrate for the cause of Allah. But if they turn away, then seize them and kill them wherever you find them and take not from among them any ally or helper.” [4:89]

The very next verse seems to exempt non-violent Apostates from being killed:

“Except for those who take refuge with a people between yourselves and whom is a treaty or those who come to you, their hearts strained at [the prospect of] fighting you or fighting their own people. And if Allah had willed, He could have given them power over you, and they would have fought you. So if they remove themselves from you and do not fight you and offer you peace, then Allah has not made for you a cause [for fighting] against them.” [4:90]

As I understand it, these verses in context mean only violent Apostates (traitors) are to be killed.
Is this interpretation accurate? If not, how should verse [4:90] be interpreted?

Comment: @Shoaib The answer to that question seems ambiguous. It states Apostates (with no indication of violent or non-violent) can be killed, then gives an example of Apostates "who fought against Islam" as the reason for killing Apostates. I'd like to get a clear answer concerning just non-violent Apostates. Perhaps my question would be more clear if I rephrased it this way: "Does verse [4:90] in the Quran exclude non-violent Apostates from being killed?" What do you think; is this more clear?

Comment: If you go through all the answers in that post you'll find your question sufficiently addressed; simple apostasy versus complete apostasy.